# Inability to map Git Repository into a Java Project in Eclipse Juno with JDK 1.6?

Tags: java, eclipse, github

I am trying to add a project in my Eclipse that is forked from the Github. It is a starter code and this is the first time Iam working with Git. I am under the impression that the Git code will come into my Eclipse environment under some Folder structure. But I am not able to map the source code into my Local. Steps I have followed are the following :-

```
    * Created repository in Github. 
    * Forked the project. 
    * Setup username and user email from Git Shell application.
    * Cloned the repository in my Git Desktop application. 
    * Using Team Command in Eclipse I tried adding project Share project, but the forked project that I want to be present there is not displaying.
```

Pardon my inability to identify certain obvious infos. let me know if any info is missing and ill append the info here.

Along with that here is the image of the package explorer.

[image]

As you can see the newsindexer-1 is the project that I have downloaded from Github. But I was under the impression that when I run configuration the Runner.java or Tester.java I would be able to pass some arguments. But I cant. Plus when I go to properties I don't see
any option of giving the Java Class Path et cetera.

Comment: Because eclipse is not recognizing it as java project. Have you tried adding java facet to project?

Comment: I tried Adding a Facet in Eclipse. The Project Facet is Java and runtime available is jre6. Is this what you are looking for(I am doing facet for the first time. I am not sure if this setting is what we are looking for.

Comment: see answer below. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow following steps to add `java` facet to your project

- In the Project Explorer, right-click the project (newsindexer-1) and then select Properties, or right click on project and check `Configure` options
- Select the Project Facets page in the in the Properties window. This page lists the facets in the project and their versions. Check on `java` facet there
- Click on apply. see if `J` appears in your Project listing. (Like you have on you *NewsIndexer* project)

Comment: It worked mate.. Although I have another problem now But your answer did the trick..Tx Bud.. If only I could upvote you or maybe give some bounty